# How to check whether a user is admin or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
if(user_id != 'admin'){
    if(author === 'admin' || author === 'Admin' || author === 'ADMIN'){
        write_message = "You can't use admin NickName!";
        res.redirect('/write');
    }
}
else {
    conn.query(sql,[title,author,contents,user_id],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            res.redirect('/menu/'+before_page);
        }
    });
}
```

Making users can't use admin 'author' but "if(user_id != 'admin')" here doesn't work.

Keep going through first 'if(user_id != 'admin')' not 'else' even I login by admin id. How can I check if author is admin or not?

Comment: Could you provide the full-source file, please? `if` statement condition is ...

Comment: Also, want to note that it is a bad practice to have any rights based on user name.  Not sure what this project is, but you should probably not rely on 'admin' for anything real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment though this may be an answer to your question. Unfortunately, I am having trouble understanding your summary of the situation.

You can have the if statement set up like so instead of having deep nesting and long if statements:

```
if(user_id != 'admin' && author.toLowerCase() === 'admin'){
    write_message = "You can't use admin NickName!";
    res.redirect('/write');
} 
else {
    conn.query(sql,[title,author,contents,user_id],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            res.redirect('/menu/'+before_page);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked!! My miss was I forgot to use toLowerCase() function... And user_id variable doesn't worked so fixed it thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Cheers, brother!